# Nginx location not resolved

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to have my nginx instance host from two separate static files.

The config for root path works but using any other prefix pattern gives 404 not found.

The config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.saurabhharwande.com;
    root         /var/www/certbot;

    location /abc/ {
        index  vindex.html;
    }

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

[www.saurabhharwande.com](http://www.saurabhharwande.com/) Works

[www.saurabhharwande.com/abc](http://www.saurabhharwande.com/abc) Gives 404

Am I missing something?

***Edit:*** My basic understanding of how nginx configuration works was flawed. I thought that index file is searched in the root itself /<domain>/<root>/index.html and location is just used to point to different roots. It is rather searched at <domain>/<root>/<location>/index.html

Comment: *Am I missing something?* - perhaps `vindex.html` itself. Is it there and with proper access rights?

Comment: vindex.html exists and when I use that file under location / it does load. So I don't think access is an issue. the location itself is not getting resolved.

Comment: `vindex.html` is located in : `/var/www/certbot/abc`?

Comment: No its at /var/www/certbot/vindex.html

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelzim Thanks for pointing it out. It works after moving to file to abc folder